# React how apply css style for spcifc part of an page which I am getting from api respose

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing an react web view app. Where user can see view of any website. Let you explain how my app is working.

**>** user submit url **->** I am sending the url to my backend using axois post **->** my backend processing the url and returning HTML to my fondend

Now sometimes my whole website design broken and also getting some error due to css and js code which have in HTML response. I just want css will be apply inside this specific div element   and it will not effect on my whole page css and don't want to execute any js. my code which I tried:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import HTMLRenderer from './HTMLRenderer';

function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch HTML content from server
   
    const fetchHTML = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('your_api_endpoint');
        const data = await response.text();
        setHtmlContent(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching HTML:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchHTML();
  }, []);

  return (
    {/* my other components */}  
    <div className="webview">
     
      <HTMLRenderer htmlContent={htmlContent} />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is `HTMLRenderer`, does it make use of the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? And what is the response from the API? Are you able to apply styling to classes or ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not going to work for a host of reasons. Among them:

- References to assets like images and CSS files are often relative, requiring you to rewrite the URLs referencing them before insertion
- CSS frequently references images, fonts, and other CSS files relatively, again requiring rewriting
- Images sometimes have hotlinking prevention—that is, the server serving them checks that they're being loaded from the expected/allowed website
- Many websites require JS to render content correctly, thus the HTML available from the initial request is not always sufficient to render the page

This all said, there is a new [@scope](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-6/#scoped-styles) proposal in CSS that would do what you're looking for regarding preventing CSS styles from impacting your page, but it isn't shipping in any browsers yet. Without it, you would need to parse all of the styles (files and inline) and rewrite the selectors to scope them to the containing element on your page. If there are media queries, this will be more complex, as will `:root` selectors, instances where a selector mentions a global element like `html` or `body`, and so on.